# Change tab text color ifroom

Tags: android, android-theme

How can I change the color of tab text from white to black when "ifroom"?

I mean, when the activity is on mode portrait, the tab text is black, but when is on mode landscape AND ifroom is true, the text should be black.

I have a custom theme:

```
<style name="Theme.mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle.mytheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabTextStyle.mytheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
  <!-- This color should be white when tabs are on mode ifroom -->
</style>
```